# JOptionPane inputs

Tags: java, joptionpane

I'm new to Java, and I have to write a Java application that will ask the user to type in a sentence using a JOptionPane input dialog, go
through each of the characters in the input and count the number of upper case letters, lower case letters and
digits, and then print the counts using a `JOptionPane` message dialog. The application should then repeat this
process until the user types the word STOP (or Stop, or STop, etc.)

I think what I have so far does most of what I need it to do,but for some reason, the program ignores all other input except for when I type stop, which isn't meant to be part of the string, but the exit word. I appreciate the help and explanations.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 
public class Project0 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String string1 = ""; 
    while(!string1.equalsIgnoreCase("Stop")){
        string1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input words or type 'stop' to end.");
        string1 += string1;
    }
    charcount(string1);



}
public static void charcount(String userin){
    int uppercount, lowercount, digitscount; variables
    uppercount = 0;
    lowercount = 0;
    digitscount = 0;

    for(int c = 0; c < userin.length(); c++ ){ 
        char ch = userin.charAt(c); 
        if(Character.isUpperCase(ch)){ uppercount += 1; } 
        else if(Character.isLowerCase(ch)){ lowercount += 1; } 
        else if(Character.isDigit(ch)){ digitscount += 1; }

    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are " + uppercount + " uppercase characters, " + lowercount + " lowercase characters and " + digitscount + " digits."); 
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few logical errors:

```
while(!string1.equalsIgnoreCase("Stop")){
        string1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input words or type 'stop' to end.");
        string1 += string1;// gets doubled the input, resulting into infinite loop
    }
    charcount(string1);// possibly has to be inside loop
```

Try instead:

```
String string1;
do {
    string1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input words or type 'stop' to end.");
    charcount(string1);
} while("stop".equalsIgnoreCase(string1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you do your code:

`while(!string1.equalsIgnoreCase("Stop")){
    string1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input words or type 'stop' to end.");
    string1 += string1;
}`

You should check to see if `string1` equals "stop". If it doesn't, cool, add like you already are doing, however if not, `break` the loop.

Since `string1` is already created, I would suggest a `do-while` type loop:

`do {
    string1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...);
    if (!string1.equalsIgnoreCase("Stop") {
        // Add to string1
    }
} while (!string1.equalsIgnoreCase("Stop"));`

Answer (score 0):

If I am thinking correctly, this may be because, unless you type "stop" right from the beginning, your string will never **equal** "stop". For example, it's checking to see if your string **equals** "stop" (ignoring case), when you should be checking to see if it `contains` "stop". You might try the following:

```
while(!string1.contains("stop")) {
    //Run your code here.
}
```

If you are checking the string with the case ignored, then you might create a string called "checkStop" and set it equal to `string1`, then convert it to all uppercase, such as the following:

```
String checkStop = string1.toUpperCase();
```

You could also convert it to lowercase:

```
String checkStop = string1.toLowerCase();
```

Then, you could use `checkStop` to determine whether or not the string contains "STOP" or "stop".